# rails too many open files using Feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

I am getting a LoadError - "Too many open files" when using Feedzirra. I am running it on my development server using the default WEBrick server.

I am parsing only 2 feeds. What is the problem?

Comment: Any progress on this?  If not, please describe your environment and post relevant messages and code.  I just received a hit on this using Windows 8, Ruby 193p4448 and Rails 4.0.0 with Feedzirra.  However, I decreased my number of feeds to 2 and it worked.  To me, that would mean that I need to fix either Windows and/or the Thin webserver I am using.  Or, perhaps, migrate to Apache as I have planned to do at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Feedzirra. You can notice that it leaves TCP connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state forever, hence causing the problem.

It appears to be `curb` gem specific that is used to fetch feeds. Another project depending on libcurl [had the same issue](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/205). They have fixed it by setting ['CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE'](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTFORBIDREUSE) option.

I've tried to do the same for Feedzirra but didn't succeed. Even with this option I had a growing number of `CLOSE_WAIT` sessions and `Too many open files` error eventually.

So I did the most straightforward thing, I download feeds using `Net::HTTP`:

```
def get_contents(furl)
  url = URI.parse(furl)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)

  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
    http.request(req)
  }

  unless res.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
    puts "can't get feed #{url.to_s}: #{res.code}"
    return nil
  end

  res.body
end
```

Then I parse the XML with Feedzirra:

```
xml = get_contents(furl)
feedin = Feedzirra::Feed.parse xml
```

No more stuck connections and no more errors. You may also want to add better error handling to this sample code.